# Prevent Visio 2016 from creating curve connector bend points?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I have a state machine diagram that consists of a series of shapes, and many curve connectors that connect from the center of one shape to somewhere on the radius of another shape. There are many cases where for two shapes A and B, there are multiple connectors that connect the center of A to the radius of B. I have two problems:

1. When I create a new connector, visio always uses a straight-downward initial angle for the connector, even if the destination shape is above the source connection point.
2. Visio always creates excessive amounts of bend points in my curves, especially when it has to bend over backwards to accommodate an initial downward angle, and each of these bend points must tediously be deleted so that changing the initial angle doesn't make the curve look insane.
3. When attempting to move the shapes themselves, visio **replaces the bend points that I deleted**.

The deal breaker is really point 3 above, since the only reason I'm even putting myself through using Visio is to allow for changes to the layout, but when it completely changes the structure of the connectors like this the value is lost.

Is there a way to prevent visio from adding bend points to my curves? I really only want the angular controls at each of the connection points, with no bend points unless absolutely necessary. At present I don't know that that necessity exists.

Comment: 1. Is the state machine drawing based on the dataflow diagram state symbols or the UML symbols? 2. Which connector are you using?

Comment: The diagram just uses basic circle shapes. I only know enough to say that I'm using the curved connector, although if there are different types of curved connectors I'm unaware of them. My problem is that Visio appears to be using the same convoluted routing algorithm for curves that it does for right-angle connectors, rather than a simple curve--essentially it's just a right-angle connect that's drawn slightly differently. Essentially I wish it was possible for it to start with no bend points, with additional ones added by the user if necessary.

Comment: When you select the drawing tool from the ribbon or stencil it will have a name next to it. What are the names?

Comment: The shapes I used were just Shapes | Stencils | Basic Shapes | Circle, and the connectors I used were just Home | Connector, with Design | Connectors | Curved Lines selected. Does the type of shape/stencil used affect connector routing?